# Cygwin shell is overriding my Windows shell

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin

I'm not sure what I did, but I've somehow got Cygwin installed in such a way that even when I try to run an ordinary windows shell, Cygwin is interfering. I have batch scripts that I want to run in the default windows way that Cygwin complains about. I can't change them; I need to run them in the felaut shell. Is there any way to get my cmd shell back without completely uninstalling cygwin?

I did try renaming cygwin1.dll to something else, and the shell seems to work just fine until foo.bat tries to run the exe. Then I get a complaint that cygwin1.dll has moved, so it looks like cygwin is being invoked by the windows shell? I have the typical windows prompt in the cmd shell. I've even tried the powershell with the same results.

Interestingly, if I run the batch file directly from Win-R, using cmd /c, it works. So I'm pretty confused.

Comment: I've now removed it from the path all together, and as expected, that works, but I can't invoke cygwin, obviously. (Well, I can, but I have to navigate to the cygwin directly manually and invoke bash from there.)

Answer (score 0):

move the Cygwin path entry to the end of the path statement.

Comment: It is, and always has been. Still have the problem.

Comment: I had the cywin path in my path statement twice once, not sure how but I removed the one at the end not noticing the 1st entry..  probably not the issue here but...